# Execute an EventHandler on a Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, silverlight, event-handling

I'm using the `LocalMessageReceiver` and `LocalMessageSender` classes to communicate between two Silverlight applications (One in browser and other Out of browser).
I need to execute `messageReceiver.MessageReceived` in a new thread.
This is my base code:

```
public MainPage()
{
    LocalMessageReceiver messageReceiver = new LocalMessageReceiver("Msg", ReceiverNameScope.Global, LocalMessageReceiver.AnyDomain);
    messageReceiver.MessageReceived += MessageReceiver_MessageReceived; //I want to execute this in a new Thread.
    messageReceiver.DisableSenderTrustCheck = true;

    try
    {
        messageReceiver.Listen();
    }
    catch (ListenFailedException)
    {
        //to do
    }
}

private void MessageReceiver_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string command = e.Message;

    switch (command)
    {
        case "SCAN":
            e.Response = Scan(e.Message); //I need to send a response
            break;
        default:
            e.Response = "NULL";
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you want...

```
messageReceiver.MessageReceived += (s, e) => 
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MessageReceiver_MessageReceived(s, e));
```

or using threads `...new Thread(() => MessageReceiver_MessageReceived(s, e)).Start();`